# Upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 keep failing

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, do-release-upgrade

I try to upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, but I have an issue.

I tried to follow this article :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-lts

after running this command :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

When the 1022 ssh dialog appeared, I wrongly typed `n`, then I got disconnected.

Later on, I had to go to the Dashboard terminal, and restore the ssh connection.

But when I retried the command :

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

it gave me this message, and I had to close the terminal :

```
Please report this as a bug and include the files
/var/log/dist-upgrade/main.log and /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log in
your report. The upgrade has aborted.
Your original sources.list was saved in
/etc/apt/sources.list.distUpgrade.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-vgm0wvbx/xenial", line 8, in
<module>
sys.exit(main())

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-vgm0wvbx/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py",
line 242, in main
if app.run():

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-vgm0wvbx/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
line 1907, in run
return self.fullUpgrade()

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-vgm0wvbx/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
line 1725, in fullUpgrade
if not self.prepare():

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-vgm0wvbx/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
line 438, in prepare
self._sshMagic()

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-vgm0wvbx/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py",
line 328, in _sshMagic
self._view.information(summary, descr)

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-vgm0wvbx/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewText.py",
line 176, in information
readline()

File
"/tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-vgm0wvbx/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeViewText.py",
line 50, in readline
s = input()

KeyboardInterrupt
=== Command terminated with exit status 1 (Tue Feb  4 01:29:35 2020) ===
```

already retry several times, but it keeps failing, any clue?

Comment: Was your machine fully-upgraded before you attempted *release-upgrade*? If you made changes to python (eg. changing version to something different from default), those changes should be restored back to default before you attempt *release-upgrade*.  14.04 LTS is now EOL & thus *release-upgrade* can be more difficult (mirrors can drop support once EOL so it's on you to verify etc).  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: not sure about that, let me check the existing python version first

Comment: it's already default, which is 2.7

Comment: By `python` I was thinking `python` & particularly `python3` (`python` itself is now EOL & already gone and was auto-removed from my release I discovered only earlier today when an python2 script was called by an outdated routine I neglected to 'update'..)

Comment: so what should I do?

I have read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades, should I try to update `sources.list` and then retry the upgrade process?

Comment: I would firstly ensure `python3` provides the expected results for `python3 -V` otherwise I'd suspect that is your issue. 14.04 LTS has been EOL too long so I cannot look up (online) what the result should be (and I don't have a 14.04 LTS/ESM system to look using commands); if you're using 14.04 ESM I'd use your Advantage support options.. That link is primarily useful to ensure your system is/was fully upgraded (otherwise *release-upgrade* could fail) before attempting it.. ie. issues you needn't do if release is still supported.

Comment: I decided to restore the previous snapshot, and then retried it, it's much better now, I have finished the upgrade process, but another issue came in though, it's posted in another thread

Comment: thank you for all your support, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I finally restarted the upgrade process, by restoring VPS droplet from a snapshot, and when the 1022 ssh dialog appearing, I typed `y` and it continued to the next process until finished.

I guess when I typed `n` before, the I got kicked out from the ssh session and it broke the upgrade process.

a lesson that can be learned here, always take a backup / snapshot of your servers, you'll never when you need them :)

Hopefully this helps anyone who deal with the same issue.